# Are there any natural languages that have one or more morphemes that each stand for both "other(s)" and "more"?

Tags: semantics, morphology, lexicon, quantifiers

I've been working on the quantifiers for a conlang of mine and noticed that the concepts "other" and "more" are each related to the notion of additional quantities.  So, we have these pairs of English sentences, which pairs appear to me to be synonymous.

"We needed three more loaves of bread."
"We needed three other loaves of bread."

"He shot three more bullets into the target."
"He shot three other bullets into the target."

"Nolan had three more sisters living in New Jersey."
"Nolan had three other sisters living in New Jersey."

The following post on the English Stack Exchange pointed out that "other," or at least "another," can connote difference in a way that "more" does not.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449180/what-is-the-difference-between-another-two-two-more-and-two-other

For example, consider this pair of sentences:

"The doctor prescribed more medication."
"The doctor prescribed other medication."

Obviously, these sentences are not synonymous.  "More medication" can mean "more of the same medication," whereas "other medication" refers to different medication.

However, given that one morpheme can have more than one meaning, are there any natural languages with a morpheme that means both "more" and "other," or is this ambiguity intolerable?

Comment: How about "additional" in English? "Additional medication" seems like it has the ambiguity you want.

Comment: Homonymy is so common that this is almost certainly the case. But such a language would be able to disambiguate the meanings, because as you said they have quite distinct meanings.

Comment: Why are you using the term morpheme?? more, other and another are not morphemes. The word **another** arises when adding **an** to **other** but that is not relevant to your question.

Comment: James, A morpheme does not stand on its own. It is an add-on like an **s** for a plural or third-person simple present verbs as in walk*s* or cat*s* or the ed for simple past tense: talk versus talk**ed**.

Comment: @Lambie:   I was thinking of single-morpheme terms like "more" and "other."   Draconis's comment, and yours, reminded me that a multi-morphemic term might also convey "more" and "other."

Comment: I just don't think it's useful for your question.

Comment: @Lambie.  re:  "A morpheme does not stand on its own."   I'm afraid you're mistaken.   By definition, bound morphemes can't stand on their own, but free morphemes can.  The word "roses," for example, has two morphemes:  "rose," which can stand alone, and the plural suffix, which can't.   Lots of lexical morphemes are free (in English and many other languages), but there are free grammatical morphemes as well.   In English, for example, we have "the," "and," and "of."

Comment: I repeat: if you are inventing a language, the word morpheme is not relevant to your examples. And I already mentioned the s plural morpheme. Yes, morpheme, the smallest thing with meaning. And phoneme, the smallest sound. You are inventing your language via some kind of translation when you can do it without it.